# Преобразование строки в число с плавающей точкой двойной точности C++

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, xubuntu

Каким образом в C++ можно преобразовать строку в `double` число? Пробовал с помощью `atof`, о он работает только до 4 знаков после запятой.

Comment: Ну, насчет четырех знаков - это вы погорячились :)

Comment: @Harry да, я уже понял, что проблема была именно в выводе на экран)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте функцию stod, которую добавили в 11 стандарте.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stod/

Подозреваю, что у вас может быть проблема с выводом. Посмотрите здесь как установить точность.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/